# discerning between "so high" and "such that "

Tags: conjunctions

Would you please elaborate the difference  between them?

1.The himalayas are such high mountains that no pilot wants to fly over them.

2.The himalayas are so high mountains that no pilot wants to fly over them.

Thanks

Comment: In your example the use of *so* is incorrect, only *such* can go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1.The Himalayas are such high mountains that no pilot wants to fly over them.

OK.

> 2.The Himalayas are so high <del>mountains</del> that no pilot wants to fly over them.

Now it's OK.

P.S.

> Mount Everest is so high a mountain that no pilot wants to fly over
>   it.

That, too, is OK.

and this is OK too:

> Mount Everest is a mountain so high that no pilot wants to fly over
>   it.

[ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=(so%20high%20a%20mountain)%2C(such%20a%20high%20mountain)%2C(a%20mountain%20so%20high)&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28so%20high%20a%20mountain%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28such%20a%20high%20mountain%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28a%20mountain%20so%20high%29%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that **so** and **such** can ever be interchangeable. You can say:

> The himalayas are such high mountains that no pilot wants to fly over them.

or without a noun following the adjective:

> The himalayas are so high that no pilot wants to fly over them.

or

> The himalayas mountains are so high that no pilot wants to fly over them.

This said, according to the sentence's pattern you can use either **such** or **so**.

Answer (score 0):

*So* normally acts as an adverbial that modifies adjectives or adverbs. *Such* modifies nouns or noun phrases. They are used in combination with *that* to express extremes. So in this case, *so* modifies *high* while *such* modifies *high mountains*, but the meaning between the two sentences is next to none.